# Filtering a DataGridView Twice

Tags: vb.net

I have a DataGridView with a bindingsource from an Access table. I am using this code:

```
QrysbfrmPupilsAndExamsBindingSource.Filter = "CandNumber = " & TextBox1.Text
```

to filter the datagridview by the column CandNumber. I then want to filter it again, keeping the results from the previous filter, not filtering from the full access table again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you bind a `DataTable` to a `BindingSource`, you can use an expressions using the syntax described within the [DataColumn.Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

So if you e.g. want to filter by an additional column, just use `And`:

```
yourBindingSource.Filter = String.Format("CandNumber = {0} AND Something = {1}", 
                                          TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text)
```